# Identify data in PostgreSQL database in violation of foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.6

Database `PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit` - this is on an Amazon AWS instance.

I recently identified some orphan data in one of the databases I look after when it caused a cron job to fail - this orphan data however was in violation of a foreign key constraint. After digging through the logs I found that these little queries had been ran (sadly I don't know by who - I presume their reason was to get around some triggers that discourage mass-deleting):

```
SET session_replication_role = replica;
delete from bmis.companies where company_id = 38;
SET session_replication_role = DEFAULT;
```

The data stored in `bmis.companies` is the absolute top-level data in this system - everything stems from it. I've manually been through the tables and ran deletes that basically boil down to this pseudo code:

```
delete from
    schema.table
where
    not exists(
        select
            *
        from
            schema.parent_table
        where
            parent_table.id = table.parent_id
    );
```

However I'm only human and it's entirely possible that I may have missed something - there are many tables in this system. I'm wondering if there's any reasonably easy-to-implement way of identifying data already inside the database that is in violation of the foreign keys, or even just identifying tables that contain this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much Googling I came up with the below to locate foreign key violations in my dataset - I had indeed missed a single table.

If you're wondering why I don't use `information_schema.table_constraints`, `information_schema.key_column_usage`, and `information_schema.constraint_column_usage` it's because using those tables completley falls apart for multi-column foreign keys.

Hope this helps someone someday:

```sql
do language plpgsql $$
declare
    _schemas varchar[];
    _fkey record;
    _sql text;
    _and text;
    _i integer;
    _test record;
begin
    _schemas := array['my_schema_one', 'my_schema_two']::varchar[];

    create temporary table __foreign_key_violations (
        table_name varchar,
        column_names varchar[],
        foreign_table_name varchar,
        foreign_column_names varchar[]
    ) on commit drop;

    for _fkey in(
        with
            __tables as(
                select
                    quote_ident(tables.table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(tables.table_name) as table_name
                from
                    information_schema.tables
                where
                    tables.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
                    and table_schema = any(_schemas)
                order by
                    tables.table_schema asc,
                    tables.table_name asc
            ),
            __raw_fkeys as(
                select
                    __tables.table_name,
                    pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid, true) as fkeydef
                from
                    __tables
                    inner join pg_catalog.pg_constraint on(
                        pg_constraint.conrelid = __tables.table_name::regclass
                        and pg_constraint.contype = 'f'
                    )
            )
        select
            __raw_fkeys.table_name,
            string_to_array(regexp_replace(__raw_fkeys.fkeydef, E'^FOREIGN KEY \\((.*?)\\).*$', E'\\1'), ', ') as column_names,
            regexp_replace(__raw_fkeys.fkeydef, E'^FOREIGN KEY .*? REFERENCES (.*?)\\(.*$', E'\\1') as foreign_table_name,
            string_to_array(regexp_replace(__raw_fkeys.fkeydef, E'^FOREIGN KEY .*? REFERENCES .*?\\((.*?)\\).*$', E'\\1'), ', ') as foreign_column_names
        from
            __raw_fkeys
    ) loop
        _sql := '
        select
            true as violations
        from
            ' || _fkey.table_name || ' as local_table
        where
            not exists(
                select
                    *
                from
                    ' || _fkey.foreign_table_name || ' as foreign_table
                where';

        for _i in 1 .. array_upper(_fkey.column_names, 1) loop
            _and := '';
            if _i > 1 then
                _and := 'and ';
            end if;

            _sql := _sql || '
                    ' || _and || 'local_table.' || quote_ident(_fkey.column_names[_i]) || ' is not null
                    and foreign_table.' || quote_ident(_fkey.foreign_column_names[_i]) || ' = local_table.' || quote_ident(_fkey.column_names[_i]);
        end loop;

        _sql := _sql || '
            )';

        for _i in 1 .. array_upper(_fkey.column_names, 1) loop
            _sql := _sql || '
                and local_table.' || quote_ident(_fkey.column_names[_i]) || ' is not null';
        end loop;

        _sql := _sql || '
        limit 1
        ';

        execute _sql into _test;

        if _test.violations = true then
            insert into __foreign_key_violations (
                table_name,
                column_names,
                foreign_table_name,
                foreign_column_names
            ) values (
                _fkey.table_name,
                _fkey.column_names,
                _fkey.foreign_table_name,
                _fkey.foreign_column_names
            );
        end if;
    end loop; -- _fkey in..
end;
$$;

select * from __foreign_key_violations;
```